# How to configure Apache to log IPs of invalid HTTP requests

Tags: apache-2.4, logging

My Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) creates access log entries with pseudonymized IPs:

```
88.130.0.0 88.130.0.0 - - [09/Aug/2020:11:30:51 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 279 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
```

When I connect with ncat and do an invalid HTTP request, the IP is not logged.

```
[09/Aug/2020:11:31:38 +0200] "test\n" 400 226
```

How do I configure Apache to log the IP in this case, too?

---

The following log format is used:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Logging is enabled using this VirtualHost directive:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Pseudonymization is done with mod_log_ipmask (https://github.com/webfactory/mod_log_ipmask).

Comment: How exactly did you already configure Apache's logging?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I tried disabling the module, resulting in unmasked IPs for valid requests, but still no IPs for invalid requests.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I added some information on logging configuration. Please let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

The output of

`apache2ctl -DDUMP_CONFIG | grep -vE "^[ ]*#[ ]*[0-9]+:"`

showed that the logging configuration for `<VirtualHost xxx:80>` differed from the logging configuration for `<VirtualHost xxx:443>`. It works as expected now.